# Is there a way to change how Flutter load assets by resolution (2.0x, 3.0x)?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter Docs https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images we need to past our Images to folders 2.0x|3.0x etc.

As a example, we have:

...icons/stackoverflow.png,

...icons/2.0x/stackoverflow.png.

In my project, I have a list icons of all countries (255 icons) and when I export from figma, it came with a [suffix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM8A1.png). It's gonna be hard rename all icons.

Is there a way to change how Flutter read assets to accept suffix in the assets? In 2.0x folder, load assets with @2x suffix and in 3.0x load assets with @3x suffix.